# Split dictionary of any amount into separate dictionaries?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

How would I successfully run a for loop through this so it prints like so.

```
names = {"James" : "18",
"Bob" : "19",
"adam": "39"
}
```

I want it to output as so:

```
Name1 = {"James" : "18"}
Name2 = { "Bob" : "19"}
Name3 = { "adam": "39"}
```

I have tried using for loops but I have been very unsuccessful. 
I have tried:

```
names.items()
```

returns:

```
dict_items([('adam', '39'), ('Bob', '19'), ('James', '18')])
```

but I need it to return in separate dictionaries as shown above.

Comment: Please show the code you have used ?

Comment: It's simply not possible, because dictionaries are unordered (at least before 3.6) and therefore `Name1` could be `{"James" : "18"}` or `{"Bob": "19"}` or `{"adam": "39"}`. Same for the others. Besides: updating globals or locals in a loop doesn't seem like a good idea.

Comment: @MSeifert The author did not precise ordered was needed, he probably just want to "split" the dictionnary.

Comment: @Delgan Are you sure? I'm not even sure if the output should be printed, assigned to globals/locals or some sort of other dictionary/list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i, (k,v) in enumerate(names.items(), 1):
    print('Name%d = %r' % (i, {k:v}))

Name1 = {'Bob': '19'}
Name2 = {'adam': '39'}
Name3 = {'James': '18'}
```

Note dictionaries are not ordered, so the order here is arbitrary.  If you need specific ordering, you can create `names` as an `OrderedDict` to start with, and this code will do what you want.

EDIT: since you mentioned you need to store duplicate keys, you can do it like this:

```
names = [("James", "18"),
        ("Bob", "9"),
        ("adam", "39")]
for i, (k,v) in enumerate(names, 1):
    print('Name%d = %r' % (i, {k:v}))
```

Comment: This deviates a bit from the expected output which contained several (seemingly random) whitespaces after the `{` and before the `:`.

Comment: @MSeifert your point being? is that a comment about my answer, or the question?  Are you suggesting adding code for randomly adding whitespaces?

Comment: My point is that your answer (as it currently stands) is totally deviating from the expected output. It may be correct though (who knows)!

Comment: @shx2 Hey this was a great solution, however when the names are the same for example: 
names = {"Bob" : "18",
"Bob" : "19",
"Bob": "39"
}

it only prints out the last dictionary: 

Name1 = {'Bob': '39'}

How would I fix this?

Comment: @PythonNLMB dictionaries can only hold a single value per key.  No duplicate keys.  If you need multiple values per "key", use a list of 2-tuples instead of a dict.

Comment: @PythonNLMB, by the way, I'm just wondering, why did you unaccept my answer?

Comment: @shx2 I'll reaccept it now.. but its because it did not work with duplicate keys, so can you edit it and add a solution for duplicate keys? Thanks!